# Мерцания при "двойной буферизации" Java awt

Tags: графика, awt, java

Использую Java awt.
При перерисовывании в появляются мерцания. Пробовал сделать двойную буферизацию, но мерцания все ровно остались.

```
public class SignatureCanvas extends Canvas{

private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
private Image buffer = null;

private void cleanPoints()
{
    points.clear();
}

public SignatureCanvas() {
    super();
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new SigCanvasMouseMotionListener(this));
    this.addMouseListener(new SigCanvasMouseListener(this));
    System.out.println(isDoubleBuffered());
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    buffer = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    Graphics gBuf = buffer.getGraphics();

    gBuf.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    gBuf.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    gBuf.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for(int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        Point p1 = points.get(i);
        Point p2 = points.get(i);
        gBuf.drawLine((int)p1.getX(), (int)p1.getY(), (int)p2.getX(), (int)p2.getY());
    }

    g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    Point tmp = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    points.add(tmp);
    this.repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
}}

class SigCanvasMouseListener implements MouseListener{
private SignatureCanvas canvas;

public SigCanvasMouseListener(SignatureCanvas c) {
    canvas = c;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    canvas.mouseReleased(e);
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}}

class SigCanvasMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener{

private SignatureCanvas canvas;

public SigCanvasMouseMotionListener(SignatureCanvas c) {
    canvas = c;
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    canvas.mouseDragged(e);
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сорри за офтоп, нокак то раз я задал похожий вопрос, и мне посоветовали бросать аwt и юзать swing

Comment: Проблему решил, если интересно ответ в комментарии к моему вопросу.

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему.

Для того чтобы не было мерцания, нужно перегружать не `paint(Graphics g)`, а `update(Graphics g)`. 
Не знаю с чем это связано, может быть кто нибудь пояснит? так как почти во всех статьях в интернете перегружается `paint`.

P.S. использую java 1.7.0

Comment: Посмотрите, [здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callback) кое-что пишут по поводу ситуаций в которых вызываются paint()  и update().

Я глубоко не вдавался, но впечатление такое, что paint() вызывают каждый раз, когда что-то можно рисовать, а update(), когда не рисовать уже нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.
Вероятно вот он ответ на вопрос 
"If the component did not override update(), the default implementation of update() clears the component's background (if it's not a lightweight component) and simply calls paint()".